# Android: Using getResources might be causing my app to crash

Tags: java, android, xml, colors, android-logcat

I don't know why this is causing my app to crash. I have instantiated 3 class variables to point to the color values I created in my colors.xml file. I have been experimenting, and the code that is commented out here seems to be causing the error "appName has stopped working"

```
protected int m_nDarkColor = R.color.dark;
//protected int m_nDarkColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.dark);
protected int m_nLightColor = R.color.light;
//protected int m_nLightColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.light);
protected int m_nTextColor = R.color.text;
//protected int m_nTextColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.text);

private boolean isDark = false; //To alternate between colors.
```

This is the method that is using the class variables on top. If I use the uncommented class variables in the setBackgroundColor() methods, the color is the same gray shade no matter what I change the color values to (that is why I commented those out too), so I tried setBackgroundColor(getResources()get.Color(R.color.dark) and it fixed the problem, but it made my class variables useless. I don't mean to be picky, I am just confused why when I set the class variable to point to my colors values in colors.xml, it causes my app to stop working or the smae gray color, but when I pass it to the setBackgroundColor method it works just fine.
`

```
protected void addJoke(String strJoke) {

    android.widget.TextView display = new android.widget.TextView(this);

    display.setText(strJoke); //Sets the text on display.

    display.setTextSize(16); //Increases the font size of the text.

    display.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text));
    //display.setTextColor(m_nTextColor);

    if(!isDark)
    {
        display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark));
        //display.setBackgroundColor(m_nDarkColor);
        isDark = true;
    }
    else if(isDark)
    {
        display.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light));
        //display.setBackgroundColor(m_nLightColor);
        isDark = false;
    }
    m_vwJokeLayout.addView(display); //Adds the view to the layout.
}
```

This is all the red from LogCat

```
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   instantiate activity ComponentInfo{edu.calpoly.android.lab2/edu.calpoly.android.lab2.SimpleJokeList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at edu.calpoly.android.lab2.SimpleJokeList.<init>(SimpleJokeList.java:34)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
09-17 20:47:25.852: E/AndroidRuntime(11212):    ... 11 more
```

Final Note: The way the code is set up now works, the colors come out right and the app runs on my device, the error is only caused when I switch the commented code with the uncommented code. This is my first question on here, so I hope it hasn't been asked before and I formatted it correctly, thanks for help!

Comment: are those classes activity classes and did you instantiate the activity class?

Comment: The class which contains this method extends the Activity class, if that helps

Comment: did you indtantiate those classes

Comment: Yes, they have been instantiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine like this: **R.color.dark** is like a **pointer** point to the value of color(Certainly not a real pointer like C language). And you use **getResources().getColor(R.color.dark)** method to get the real value of color.

Do a test:

```
   Log.d("Color", "Value of \"R.color.gray\" is: " + R.color.gray);
   Log.d("Color", "Value of \"getResources().getColor(R.color.gray)\" is: " + getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
```

Here is the output in logCat:

```
09-18 11:07:17.458  32359-32359/com.ch.summerrunner D/Color﹕ Value of "R.color.gray" is: 2131099651
09-18 11:07:17.458  32359-32359/com.ch.summerrunner D/Color﹕ Value of "getResources().getColor(R.color.gray)" is: -2144128205
```

the value -2144128205 means the real color in Android system.
May this help you.

-----------add--------------

I understand what you mean.

Why your app crashes?

Because **getResources() method return null**.

But why it return null when you call it to set the class variable?

Long Story.

getResource() is a interface of Context and implement by ContextWrapper. Like this :

```
  @Override
  public Resources getResources()
  {
      return mBase.getResources();
  }
```

But the Constructor of ContextThemeWrapper（Subclasses of ContextWrapper） is :

```
  public ContextThemeWrapper() {
        super(null);
    }
```

and

```
  public ContextThemeWrapper(Context base, int themeres) {
        super(base);
        mBase = base;
        mThemeResource = themeres;
    }
```

You can see that the **mBase** of ContextWrapper may be null.

This is the Constructor of Activity(Subclasses of ContextThemeWrapper):

```
public Activity ()
```

[Activity Constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#Activity())

We did not pass a context to Activity, so when did ContextWrapper initialize **mBase** ?

When system create/start an Activity, system pass a **mBase** instance to Activity by **attachBaseContext(Context base)** method of Activity.

This is why you get NULL when you call getResources() to set the class variable.

**You call the method too early. Call getResources() in onCreate() of later.**

There may be some mistakes in this answer, if you wanna know more, read the source:

```
frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java
```

Comment: I guess that would explain the gray color, but when I do set the class variable to the getResources().getColor(R.color.dark) method, the app crashes, any ideas as to why?

Comment: @Jerryq27 you should not instantiate a activity class. You only declare activities in manifest file\

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the thorough answer and for breaking it down, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getResources()` too early in the activity lifecycle.

The activity is usable as a `Context` only in `onCreate()` or later. Instance initialization (`<init>` in your stacktrace) is too early. Move the `getResources()` and such to `onCreate()` or later.

Answer (score 0):

I added iconics to app then after remove that from application I comment the code on attachBaseContext. App started to give this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

After I remove attachBaseContext completely, everything is fine.

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase)
    {
        //super.attachBaseContext(IconicsContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```